# Controlling context in jQuery button proxy function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to isolate the value attached to a button when it is clicked in jQuery. However, I also need to wrap the click handler in `$.proxy(...)` so that the context is maintained for subsequent function calls:

```
$('#' + tab.buttonId).click($.proxy(function() {
   this.pop($(this).val());
}, this));
```

- this.pop needs to apply to the object
- $(this).val() would need to come from the button

How do I make each call to `this` reference the right thing?

Comment: what object is `this`? In the context of the click event `this` should always represent the button element.

Comment: the first `this` (this.pop) is the object that this click handler is inside - as determined in the proxy, the second `this` should be the button - just need to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `e.target` it will point to button object:

```
$('#' + tab.buttonId).click($.proxy(function(e) {
   this.pop($(e.target).val());
}, this));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the this you are passing should be inside the proxy function arguments:

```
$('#' + tab.buttonId).click($.proxy(function() {
   this.pop($(this).val());
}, this));
```

Comment: no :( i had that in my code but not on stack overflow. the issue is that i need "this" to really mean two things at the same time - i need to figure out how to keep the proxy but still figure out what button initiated this call.

Comment: What other thing do you need to make reference to? the jquery object and what else?

Comment: the jquery object and the button that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I would store the context in a variable:

```
// the context
var that = this;
$('#' + tab.buttonId).click(function() {
   that.pop($(this).val());
});
```

This is common practise, and a future reader understands it without the knowledge about `$.proxy`

Answer (score 0):

Use the event object for the thing you clicked on. `e.target`

```js
function pop(val) {
  alert(val.text())
}

$('a').click($.proxy(function(e) {
  this.pop($(e.target));
}, this));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Other options: use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
     this.pop($(e.target));
}.bind(this));
```

Or es6 arrow functions, which will keep the lexical `this`

```
$('a').click(e => {
    this.pop($(e.target));
});
```